# How to split particular data within json using splitjson processor in Apache Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have this data and I need to split `VisitList's` content into different flowfile one by one.

What should I write in `JsonPath Expression` so that data got split, I tried `$.*` but then it is considering this given data into one file only while I want to split on the basis of VisitList.

**Data**

```
[
  {
    "employer": "98765",
    "loc_id": "312",
    "topId": "Management",
    "VisitList": [
      {
        "S1": "HR",
        "S2": "Accountant"
      },
      {
        "S1": "Manager",
        "S2": "Sr. Manager"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to split Data into files like this
1st flowfile

```
[
  {
    "employer": "98765",
    "loc_id": "312",
    "topId": "Management",
    "VisitList": [
      {
        "S1": "HR",
        "S2": "Accountant"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

2nd flowfile

```
[
  {
    "employer": "98765",
    "loc_id": "312",
    "topId": "Management",
    "VisitList": [
      {
        "S1": "Manager",
        "S2": "Sr. Manager"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried putting $.* in JsonPath Expression but it didnt work the way I want.